# Laravel (nova) inheritance mapping

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-nova

I'm currently building a laravel nova application.
I'd like to be able to achive something similar to what Doctrine can do via [inheritance mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Let's assume the following example:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Event extends Model {
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => null,
        'starts_at' => null,
        'ends_at' => null,
    ];
}

class EventTypeA extends Event {
  // has extra fields specific to EventTypeA
}

class EventTypeB extends Event {
  // has extra fields specific to EventTypeB
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to:

1. Fetch all `EventTypeA`'s
2. Fetch all `EventTypeB`'s
3. Fetch all Events and just care about the shared information.

Of course for the above list all Eloquent goodness such as filtering, projecting, etc. should apply.

---

As far as I am aware laravel *might* be able to hanle `EventTypeA` and `EventTypeB` correctly however `Event` would have to need to fetch data from two tables which is not really possible.

I am aware of eloquent's morphing feature, however from my understanding that would result in seperate nova views for the `Event` core data and descendant specific attributes. This is not acceptable in terms of UX.

I thought about using an interface for `Event` which `EventTypeA` and `EventTypeB` would then implement. However I assume this would involve a lot of manual labor to get Eloquent to do something meaningful with the Events then.

This sounds like such a common problem, however I wasn't able to find any resources on how to do this the proper way in laravel (especially so that nova can coup with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't provide a solution to create a base model with child classes for different tables. The other way round is perfectly possible:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
}
```

```php
class EventA extends Event
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('events.type', '=', 'a');
        });
    }
}
```

```php
class EventB extends Event
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('events.type', '=', 'b');
        });
    }
}
```

I solved similar problems by using an intermediate model for the pivot table and proxying some attributes to child models.

Then your relations would be `BelongsTo` and `HasMany`.

In terms of UX you can customize the fields in Nova by conditionally checking resource properties. Although I would recommend to do this only on detail and form views because the index table will be off when returning rows with different columns.

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return array_filter([
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        value(function () {
            if ($this->type === 'a') {
                return Boolean::make('A specific field')->hideFromIndex();
            }
        }),

        value(function () {
            if ($this->type === 'b') {
                return Boolean::make('B specific field')->hideFromIndex();
            }
        }),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Accepted it since it's a vanilla solution. See my post for a 3rd party package solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently found out about [`kirschbaum-development/nova-inline-relationship`](https://packagist.org/packages/kirschbaum-development/nova-inline-relationship)
This package allows you to inline relations into a nova resource and hence would allow a sturcture like:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
  public function eventable()
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

```php
class Workshop extends Model
{
  public function event()
  {
    return $this->morphOne(Event::class, 'eventable');
  }
}
```

```php
class StageTalk extends Model
{
  public function event()
  {
    return $this->morphOne(Event::class, 'eventable');
  }
}
```

And then in the nova resource

```php
class Workshop extends Resource
{
  public function fields(Request $request)
  {
  return [
    MorphOne::make('Event')->inline(),
  ];
  }
}
```